# AWS CDK - Connect a Network Load Balancer and a Neptune Cluster Endpoint together

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

For the past two days I've been struggling with exposing a Neptune endpoint to the public using an NLB **in a single stack**. The architecture was inspired by [this document](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dbs-refarch-graph/tree/master/src/connecting-using-a-load-balancer#connecting-to-amazon-neptune-from-clients-outside-the-neptune-vpc-using-aws-network-load-balancer).

For the life of me I haven't been able to figure out how to obtain the IP address of the Neptune endpoint to use as the target of NLB's listener. The main issue resides in the conversion of the Neptune `hostname` to an IP address as required by NLB's target group `IPTarget` and how CDK synthesizes stacks before deployment.

I explored the use of CustomResources to no avail due to my limited familiarity with the topic (day 5 of my aws journey), and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Here's my stack (CDK app repo [here](https://github.com/neuxregime/cdk-neptune-nlb)):

```js
import { Construct } from "constructs";
import { Stack } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import * as ec2 from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2";
import * as elbv2 from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2";
import * as neptune from "@aws-cdk/aws-neptune-alpha";

import { Props } from "../../_config";
import createVPC from "../helpers/createVPC";
import createNeptuneCluster from "../helpers/createNeptuneCluster";
import createNLB from "../helpers/createNLB";

export class ABCGraphStack extends Stack {
  public readonly vpc: ec2.Vpc;

  public readonly subnets: {
    public: ec2.ISubnet[];
    private: ec2.ISubnet[];
    isolated: ec2.ISubnet[];
  };
  
  public readonly neptuneCluster: neptune.DatabaseCluster;
  public readonly neptuneReadEndpoint: neptune.Endpoint;
  public readonly neptuneWriteEndpoint: neptune.Endpoint;
  public readonly nlb: elbv2.NetworkLoadBalancer;

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: Props) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // Create VPC for use with Neptune
    const { vpc, subnets } = createVPC(props, this);
    this.vpc = vpc;
    this.subnets = subnets;

    // Create Neptune Cluster
    this.neptuneCluster = createNeptuneCluster(
      props,
      this,
      this.vpc,
      this.subnets
    );

    // Update Neptune Security Group to allow-all-in
    this.neptuneCluster.connections.allowDefaultPortFromAnyIpv4(
      "Allow All Inbound to Neptune"
    );

    // Add an ordering dependency on VPC.
    this.neptuneCluster.node.addDependency(this.vpc);

    // Output the Neptune read/write addresses
    this.neptuneReadEndpoint = this.neptuneCluster.clusterReadEndpoint;
    this.neptuneWriteEndpoint = this.neptuneCluster.clusterEndpoint;

   // HOW TO GET IP ADDRESS OF this.neptuneWriteEndpoint.hostname?

    // Create Network Load Balancer
    this.nlb = createNLB(props, this, this.vpc, "????????", 8182);
    this.nlb.node.addDependency(this.neptuneCluster);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to access the this.neptuneCluster.clusterEndpoint.socketAddress? See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-neptune-alpha-readme.html

Comment: @A.K. Yes, but this is not resolved until the whole stack is deployed. It only shows as `$TOKEN###` when I log to console. Even then, I need to access and resolved this to an IP address like "10.0.1.31" at synthesis time.

Comment: In that case I believe youll have to do it the opposite way. The DatabaseCluster in Neptune is of type IConnectable (See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-neptune-alpha.DatabaseCluster.html. If you create your Application listener separately and bind that to a LB you can then call the registerConnectable method. You'll still need to specify port, but that should be a constant. This should resolve at deployment time

Comment: See the method registerConnectable here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-elasticloadbalancingv2.IApplicationListener.html